# I am unable to dispatch two actions together in react thunk

Tags: react-native

I am fetching two APIs in parallel and I want to render the data together but I am unable to render the data from the second API.

I am attaching the expo link of the project.

https://snack.expo.dev/@keshav1973/thunk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let minify `fetchUsers` function as below

```
const getLinksDataPromises =  async ()=> {

  const links = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users","https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"]

  return links.map( async link=> { 
    
   const response =  await fetch(link)

   const data = await  response.json()
    return data
    
    })
}

export const fetchUsers = () => {

  return async  dispatch => {

    dispatch(getUsersRequest());
  
      const promises = await getLinksDataPromises()
      const results = await Promise.all(promises);

       const users = results[0]
       const posts =  results[1]

   dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS', payload: users})
   dispatch({ type: 'GET_POSTS_SUCCESS', payload: posts})
     
  };
};
```

The issue was not copying the previous state value before you update the new value. That's why the second dispatch clear the previous dispatched value.

Updated reducer function

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  posts: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const users = (state = initialState, action) => {

  console.log({action})
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_USERS_REQUEST':
      return {...state, loading: true};
    case 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS':
      return {...state,loading: false, users: action.payload};
    case 'GET_USERS_FAILURE':
      return {...state,loading: false, error: action.payload};
       case 'GET_POSTS_SUCCESS':
         return {...state,loading: false, posts: action.payload,}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default users;
```

You can test working example here

https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/230e21

Comment: Can you approve the answer for future dev reference